# How do I binary serialize a object using Compact Framework?

Tags: serialization, compact-framework

I have a object

```
struct _NETINFO { }
```

and I want to convert it to a Byte[] using Compact Framework, I tried the following without sucess:

```
_NETINFO info = new _NETINFO();
byte[] buffer = (byte[])info;
```

And it doesn't work! The only other sugestion I found is to use the BinaryFormatter which isn't available in CF!

Any other sugestions?

Comment: What about extracting the BinaryFormatter class from the full framework?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CF_serializer.aspx, or this: http://www.freewebs.com/compactFormatter/About.html, or this: http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/download/index.html

Answer (score 0):

How complex is the struct?  For simple things where you don't have pointers to other stuff, it's pretty easy:

```
    var info = new _NETINFO();
    var buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(info)];
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(info, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        Marshal.Copy(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
```

There's also a version using unsafe code that's shorter, but that requires turning on "allow unsafe code" and for some reason that makes some people panic.

Wish managed code allowed doing this without the copy (or the reverse - casting a byte array to a struct), but sadly it does not.